# Get the number of same field from a table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've the following table:

```
UserId                                  Start                   Stop

1550f503-914e-4f83-af2b-249d54cce369    2014-04-15 18:20:23.000 2014-04-15 18:21:38.000
1550f503-914e-4f83-af2b-249d54cce369    2014-04-15 18:20:23.000 2014-04-15 18:21:38.000
1550f503-914e-4f83-af2b-249d54cce369    2014-04-15 18:20:23.000 2014-04-15 18:21:38.000
1550f503-914e-4f83-af2b-249d54cce369    2014-04-15 18:20:23.000 2014-04-15 18:21:38.000
1550f503-914e-4f83-af2b-249d54cce369    2014-04-15 18:39:14.000 2014-04-15 18:40:02.000
1550f503-914e-4f83-af2b-249d54cce369    2014-04-15 18:41:17.000 2014-04-15 18:46:08.000
1550f503-914e-4f83-af2b-249d54cce369    2014-04-15 19:57:28.000 2014-04-15 19:59:53.000
1550f503-914e-4f83-af2b-249d54cce369    2014-04-16 08:19:48.000 2014-04-16 08:20:27.000
1550f503-914e-4f83-af2b-249d54cce369    2014-04-16 13:18:41.000 2014-04-16 14:24:23.000
7a2e5b7c-9a3a-4ad1-ad79-946bcf2bf2f3    2014-04-16 16:10:11.000 2014-04-16 16:15:53.000
7a2e5b7c-9a3a-4ad1-ad79-946bcf2bf2f3    2014-04-16 17:18:57.000 2014-04-16 17:20:09.000
7a2e5b7c-9a3a-4ad1-ad79-946bcf2bf2f3    2014-04-16 20:21:27.000 2014-04-16 20:32:40.000
7a2e5b7c-9a3a-4ad1-ad79-946bcf2bf2f3    2014-04-16 20:57:06.000 2014-04-16 20:57:41.000
7a2e5b7c-9a3a-4ad1-ad79-946bcf2bf2f3    2014-04-16 20:57:56.000 2014-04-16 21:33:47.000
7a2e5b7c-9a3a-4ad1-ad79-946bcf2bf2f3    2014-04-17 08:03:34.000 2014-04-17 08:19:42.000
7a2e5b7c-9a3a-4ad1-ad79-946bcf2bf2f3    2014-04-17 08:23:04.000 2014-04-17 08:25:18.000
7a2e5b7c-9a3a-4ad1-ad79-946bcf2bf2f3    2014-04-17 08:32:56.000 2014-04-17 08:36:13.000
7a2e5b7c-9a3a-4ad1-ad79-946bcf2bf2f3    2014-04-17 08:40:17.000 2014-04-17 08:42:01.000
7a2e5b7c-9a3a-4ad1-ad79-946bcf2bf2f3    2014-04-17 09:03:56.000 2014-04-17 09:04:07.000
7a2e5b7c-9a3a-4ad1-ad79-946bcf2bf2f3    2014-04-17 09:38:37.000 2014-04-17 09:45:55.000
7a2e5b7c-9a3a-4ad1-ad79-946bcf2bf2f3    2014-04-17 09:46:37.000 2014-04-17 09:48:35.000
7a2e5b7c-9a3a-4ad1-ad79-946bcf2bf2f3    2014-04-17 09:48:58.000 2014-04-17 09:55:27.000
7a2e5b7c-9a3a-4ad1-ad79-946bcf2bf2f3    2014-04-17 09:55:49.000 2014-04-17 09:57:11.000
7a2e5b7c-9a3a-4ad1-ad79-946bcf2bf2f3    2014-04-17 10:00:32.000 2014-04-17 10:03:32.000
7a2e5b7c-9a3a-4ad1-ad79-946bcf2bf2f3    2014-04-17 10:08:09.000 2014-04-17 10:14:04.000
7a2e5b7c-9a3a-4ad1-ad79-946bcf2bf2f3    2014-04-17 10:16:49.000 2014-04-17 10:26:29.000
7a2e5b7c-9a3a-4ad1-ad79-946bcf2bf2f3    2014-04-17 10:32:36.000 2014-04-17 10:37:42.000
7a2e5b7c-9a3a-4ad1-ad79-946bcf2bf2f3    2014-04-17 10:42:01.000 2014-04-17 10:43:23.000
8e2555b7-7d7b-410b-818e-1c62f1d9268a    2014-04-17 10:58:34.000 2014-04-17 10:58:41.000
8e2555b7-7d7b-410b-818e-1c62f1d9268a    2014-04-17 10:58:53.000 2014-04-17 10:59:49.000
8e2555b7-7d7b-410b-818e-1c62f1d9268a    2014-04-17 11:02:25.000 2014-04-17 11:04:03.000
7a2e5b7c-9a3a-4ad1-ad79-946bcf2bf2f3    2014-04-17 12:43:04.000 2014-04-17 12:43:13.000
```

You can see that in my table some of `UserId` field are repeated, so I've used the following query to distinct them and obtain a table in which the `UserId` aren't repeated:

```
select DISTINCT UserId from UserSessions
```

Now I need to get the number of time that the first UserId is repeated in the table to get the number of time that this user access to the application, so I thought to do a query like this:

```
select COUNT(UserId) from UserSessions
where UserId = (select DISTINCT UserId from UserSessions)
```

But it doesn't work, how I can solve my problem?

Comment: Why did this get a down vote? It is a valid question if you are not too familiar with SQL.

Comment: @Donal My guess would be that perhaps because it's so basic? Although if you don't know what to search for you wouldn't find an appropriate solution.

Comment: @Yuck The OP provided sample data and his attempted queries - so he should be commended for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select UserId, COUNT(UserId) from UserSessions
GROUP BY UserId
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it:

```
SELECT UserId, COUNT(UserId) 
FROM UserSessions
GROUP BY UserId
```

You don't have to include the DISTINCT USERID part in the WHERE clause, as it will group on the IDs.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple `group by` with `count` solution:

```
select UserId, count(*)
from UserSessions
group by UserId;
```

You can also get the `min(Start)` or `max(Stop)` to figure the first and last times they accessed the application.

You can add a `having count(*) > 1` clause after the group by to see who has accessed the application more than once (or any other number).

Lots of things you can do with SQL aggregation.  You should probably read a primer.

[Aggregate Functions (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx)